# Find View(s) Object(s) that contain column which is/are not available in any Table Object

Tags: sql-server

Required to find all View(s) that has column available but those column(s) not available in Table.
Example:
Tabl1 has a column1, column2
View1 has a column1, column2
Now somehow Tabl1.column2 removed without altering View1
so now View1 has column1 and column2 but Table1 has only Column1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once upon a time I wrote a small utility to check MSSQL Views (and SPs, and functions) for exactly this use case: [checktsql](https://devio.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/checking-ms-sql-server-objects/)

If you need a T-SQL-based solution, you need to loop through all views, call

```
EXEC ('SELECT TOP(1) * FROM ' + @viewname)
```

and catch the exceptions raised by the `SELECT`. [Here is a sketch](https://devio.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/checking-ms-sql-server-stored-procedures/) for the code handling stored procedures, but adaptation to views should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

A view is basically a stored query, it holds no data so it won't get updated when the tables it's built on are

```
SELECT VIEW_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT STATEMENT) AND ANY(TABLE_NAME.* IS NULL)
```

(SELECT STATEMENT meaning you select your tables you want to check)

not sure if this will work

Comment: Hi, i tried with this query but its not working. I tried another option but its not giving me correct output

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT c.COLUMN_NAME
  ,c.table_name
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
 INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON c.table_name = o.[name]
  AND o.[type] IN ('V')
 WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT c1.COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1 
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o1 ON c1.table_name = o1.[name]
   AND o1.[type] IN ('U')
 )

Comment: As i said i wasnt sure about whether it does work with the ANY(TABLE_NAME.* IS NULL) part so you could try rewriting that cause it does returns the views without the 2nd condition